# Multi-label classification: decoding one hot vector

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras, one-hot-encoding

I am currently working on a multi-label classification problem where I am trying to classify images of fruits. Once I convert categories with one hot encoding how would I decode after  I train my model and want to get the appropriate category back ?

```
a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
b = pandas.get_dummies(a)
```

**Sample**

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, b, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
```

......

**Model training**

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(6,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='lerelu'))
```

.....

**Predict**

```
model.predict(X_test[0]) --->> result  ??????
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, wouldn't it just be:

```
test_predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: b = pandas.get_dummies(a) returns a bit matrix, how will I be able to extract the categorical column name from predict for a given candidate?